# Javascript Date Time Object start at 15:00

Tags: javascript, date

I created a function that produces a loop of days in month.

Here's my code

```js
var date = new Date()
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 2);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 1);
firstDay.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
lastDay.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)

console.log('Today date: ', date)
console.log('First Day: ', firstDay)
console.log('Last Day: ', lastDay)
```

Why the First Day and Last Day starts at 17:00 ?

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you need help in? Which one starts at 17:00?

Comment: @wentjun sorry for not to be clear. I mean First Day and Last Day.

Comment: Because of your timezone (presumably +07:00).

Comment: I think it's because of timezone.

Comment: Ok, so you would prefer it to start at zero dark hundred, right? at 00:00?

Comment: For me it's `Last Day:  "2019-02-28T22:00:00.000Z"`

Comment: @str It's 16:50 so if I round it, it's about 17:00. I've edited my snippet and added a setHours() function, it's still give me 17:00.

Comment: @Skipm3 That is completely normal as dates are represented in UTC. Use [`Date#toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) to show it correctly in your current timezone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can 'force' the dates to start at zero dark hundred by doing this:

```
const date = new Date()
date.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

I suspect that your requirements might be more complex. If that is the case, you can force the user's browser/device to adopt a specific timezone, such as this:

```
date.toLocaleString('en-GB', { timeZone: 'UTC' });
```

And since you mentioned you are running it on Node.js which has a different timezone configuration,

```
const today = new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0));
const todayISO = today.toISOString();
console.log(todayISO);
```

Comment: Have you tried it? I've edited the snippet. It still give me 17:00

Comment: Yes! It gives me 00:00

Comment: Anyway, i've tried it in my browser's console. And it's gave me 00:00. But in my Node.JS console and stackoverflows' snippet, it's still give me 17:00.

Comment: Node.js uses UTC by default, not your current timezone.

Comment: Oh, for Node.js, you need to do something else. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Hmm.. I have updated it. hope it works on Node.js too?

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date()
```

This returns an object which represent the current time of the system where the command runs.

```
Thu Feb 28 2019 15:14:30 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```